# WHERE LIKE in SSIS C# script

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, where-clause

I have the query below in SSIS script.

```
string query = "Select distinct " + ColumnNameForGrouping + " from " + TableName + "where flag like '%investigation%'" ;
```

It gives me error message below.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ST_6e1c49bc23064a7f8c0538ec0e69dd09.ScriptMain.Main()
ClientConnectionId:b5c340bb-5ec2-48cb-9d2a-fd5d1ead30bd
Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15
```

I'm guessing it doesn't like the single quotation or the percent symbol. How do you write WHERE - LIKE in SSIS Script using C#?

For information, before I only used the query below without Where - LIKE clause and it worked fine.

```
string query = "Select distinct " + ColumnNameForGrouping + " from " + TableName
```

I'm using Microsoft Server 2012.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Put a space before the where. It should be + " where flag like '%investigation%'" ; You might also try adding brackets before the column name and table name if the names contain space or reserved word.

Comment: The best thing here would be for you to use prepared statements.  Then, you can write out your entire query in a single line, in one pair of double quotes, which would avoid the error the above comment fixes.

Comment: LOL such a simple solution Han. It does working. Been banging my head for 3 hours for this error. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER BY HAN :

Put a space before the where. It should be + " where flag like '%investigation%'" ; You might also try adding brackets before the column name and table name if the names contain space or reserved word. – Han 43 mins ago